# How can I make the program stop after entering a value from a user?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to write a program that receives the number of sides from the
user and determines the type of figure using switch structure and a while sentinel-controlled loop, but every time I get an infinite loop. How can that be fixed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of sides:");
        int s = input.nextInt();
        while ( s!=-1)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
            case 1: System.out.println("Line");
                break;
            case 2:System.out.println("Angle");
                break;
            case 3:System.out.println("Triangle");
                break;
            case 4:System.out.println("Quadrilateral");
                break;
            case 5:System.out.println("Pentagon ");
                break;
            case 6:System.out.println("Hexagon");
                break;
            case 7:System.out.println("Heptagon");
                break;
            case 8:System.out.println("Octagon");
                break;
            case 9:System.out.println("Nonagon");
                break;
            case 10:System.out.println("Decagon");
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Enter a valid value:");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use System.exit() for this purpose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quit a java app from within the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670956/how-to-quit-a-java-app-from-within-the-program)

Comment: Your `input` should be ***inside*** your loop,

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is written to continue as long as `s!=-1`; so you need to change `s` so that this expression is no longer true.